# Get/set functions on static properties

Tags: actionscript-3, static-methods

I've been learning about encapsulation in AS3 and using get/set functions to make variables that are (or appear to be) read only. I can get it to work with instance variables, but not static variables. I found [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/learn/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f36.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f33__WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f2c), which seems to indicate that it's possible to use get/set functions on static properties, but the compiler keeps telling me I have duplicate function declarations. This is essentially what I'm using:

```
package {
    public class Foo {
        protected static var bar:int = 0;

        public static function get bar():int {return bar;}
    }
}
```

Comment: you can not use a `variable` and `function` with some name `bar`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot create a function (including gets or sets) with the same name as a variable, otherwise you would be re-initiating the variable.

```
package {
    public class Foo {
        protected static var myVar:int = 0;

        public static function get theVar():int {return myVar;}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A good practice you can adopt is to call _bar the "internal" variable you're going to modify by getter and setter, and call them simply bar.

For example:

```
package {
    public class Foo {
         protected static var _bar:int = 0;

         public static function get bar():int {
               return _bar;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: +1 for underscore coding convention, however I mainly using underscore for private properties only.